Does topology have a place in ai
Basic knowledge of topology
How it relates to ai
Does ai need to understand or integrate topology
Can ai provide useful answers to hard topological problems

Does this answer your question? In what ways is the term "topology" applied to Artificial Intelligence?

This seems to ask two questions: 1) How does topology come in in the theoretical mathematics underlying artificial intelligence? 2) Can AI help us solve open problems in topology like the Hodge conjecture? I don't see these as the same.

This is not be a full answer to your question, but a good start I believe.
Take a look at TDA (Topological Data Analysis) and how is topology used in nlp.

YES
Cybenko's 1989 universal approximation theorem, loosely speaking, says that any "decent" function can be approximated as close as desired, using a neural network. This is part of why neural networks are so popular in many AI applications, because there is a theoretical argument for why they can fit complex relationships.
One of the technical conditions about what constitutes a "decent" function relates to the topology, chiefly set compactness.
